# About Site Association bonus after 200 reputation

Tags: discussion

So we get [Site association bonus](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)(Worth 100 reputation) after we reach at 200 reputation(That's pretty amazing feeling :)).

My question is **why it is awarded for the site on which we already have 200 reputation?**

I'm not against it(As i told it feels good :) ) but i just want to know is there any specific reason behind this?

**Edit**

Like always @sfdcfox has already come up with an excellent answer. One more issue what i feel related is **What if somebody lose the reputation on main site and go below 200 mark, will the bonus reputation be revoked from other sites as well**?

Having gut feeling the answer is in negative, but felt an honest question worth to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

It says you get 100 points on *each* site. It has no exclusions or limitations. One of the wonderful things about SO and its related sites is they always mean exactly what they say. The rules say there's a 100 reputation bonus on each site, and that's what happens. This reduces the number of questions/complaints about a "missing" 100 reputation, and reduces the explanation to just a single sentence, instead of being much more verbose about how to get the 100 points on the original site.

Also, SO tends to try to make the rules as simple as possible, so as to exclude as few people as possible. Also, this makes the underlying programming easier, too, as there's exactly only two times an update happens: once when the 200 milestone is reached, and once each time a new account is created. It's simple, precise, and gives users a nice fuzzy feeling when they get the bonus reputation.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what i was expecting.One of the first thing you have to keep in your mind if you are building such a huge application **Keep it simple**.Otherwise everybody is going to have headaches ;) .Although things become cloudy in my mind sometime so i'm updating my question with a little related scenario, i'm sure that also has straight forward answer.